# Between operator return empty result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want get records within a specific range of values. These records are available inside a table called `Product`. This table have this fields used as filters:

- min_price
- max_price
- start_date
- end_date

Suppose that I want get all records which have as filters:

- min_price = 5
- max_price = 10
- start_date = 03/04/2018
- end_date = 03/04/2018

the total records are:

```
  | id | price | datetime            |
  |  1 |   2   | 01/04/2018 00:00:00 | 
  |  2 |   5   | 03/04/2018 00:00:00 | 
  |  3 |   1   | 03/04/2018 00:00:00 | 
  |  4 |   50  | 02/04/2018 00:00:00 | 
  |  5 |   10  | 03/04/2018 00:00:00 |
```

based on the specified filters I should get this records (ID): `5, 10`.
I wrote this query:

```
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=products.sqlite;Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();

m_dbCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE " +
              "price BETWEEN :min_price AND :max_price AND " +
              "datetime BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date", m_dbConnection );

m_dbCommand.Parameters.Add("min_price", DbType.Decimal).Value = 5;
m_dbCommand.Parameters.Add("max_price", DbType.Decimal).Value = 10;
m_dbCommand.Parameters.Add("start_date", DbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2018, 04, 01);
m_dbCommand.Parameters.Add("end_date", DbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2018, 04, 03);

m_dbCommand.Prepare();

var reader = m_dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{

} //<- Breakpoint here
```

The code never enters in the loop, so the query didn't return any results.
What I did wrong in my query?

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the query simply not working with the same date intervall, so if I specify as `start_date` and `end_date` the same as: `03/04/2018 00:00:00` the query doesn't return any results. Instead, if I set as `start_date: 03/04/2018 00:00:00`, and as `end_date: 04/04/2018 00:00:00` this will work.

I tried to fix that using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE price BETWEEN :min_price AND :max_price AND datetime BETWEEN DATE(:start_date) AND DATE(:end_date)
```

and tried to format only as `Date` (though to a `time` problem):

```
m_dbCommand.Parameters.Add("start_date", DbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(2018, 04, 03).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
m_dbCommand.Parameters.Add("end_date", DbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(2018, 04, 03).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

my solution simply does not work.

Comment: Why are you passing DbType.Decimal type for date time? I think you should use datetime only.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the right database? Your con string has no path for the file and Inside a DEBUG session of Visual Studio that file is located in the subfolder BIN\DEBUG (or x86) of your project. Check if that database file contains the data that you expect to be there.

Comment: @Steve yep I'm sure. If I execute `Select * FROM Product` I'll get all records available

Comment: Could you try with _BETWEEN date('2018-04-01') AND date('2018-04-03');_

Comment: can you add the table definition? I wonder if the column datatypes match...

Comment: @bradbury9 could you check the update?

Comment: @L.Page I did, and thats why I asked for the table definition. In the question `price` columns looks like a integer column, which could be wrong (or maybe it is realy decimal and just a typo in the table data info) There are some issues regarding datetime fields in SQLite, could you check the 2.2 section of this link? could be related. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: As a side, not related note, `SQLiteCommand.Prepare()` looks like it does not do anything. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.prepare?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of the parameter, you are trying to use a decimal for a datetime field.

Comment: I was wrong to write, my code does not have that error, I corrected the question however.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Format your Date value before save into database. Because Your Date Field has Value as `01/04/2018 00:00:00` and you Pass Value to Check the Condition is `new DateTime(2018, 04, 01)`.That is `01/Apr/2018` . According to that your Database Value (`01/04/2018 00:00:00`) obviously Not Equal to Your Argument Value (`01/Apr/2018`).. So Before Save the Date value into Database You Should Format Like You Want.

Try To Use this method in your insert or Update Query as `Format(New Date(2017, 4, 5), "dd/MM/yyyy")`...this is the way store Date without time and then proceed with your Query

Comment: The `datetime` column contain also the time not only the date